# Adding children over children in windows phone 7 canvas is responding slowly

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am using canvas in wp7 silverlight application.
I am facing two problems.

1. So on Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown event capturing single point and then in MouseMove event i am capturing the other point and then drawing a line and adding this children to Canvas. Everything is going fine except that in mouse move event some points are missing between two if i move my finger a little bit fast and the result is that i am getting straight lines instead of curves.
   For grabbing point I am using e.GetPosition(where e is MouseButtonEventArgs and MouseEventArgs  type).Is there other way through which i can grab point like using Touch class.
2. If i have already drawn many lines(added many children to canvas) then adding more lines with different color over prior lines is slow and points are missing again resulting in straight lines. I think its happening becos capturing of points in MouseMove events over already drawn area is becoming slow and middle points are missing.

So please suggests me any solutions or way to handle this problematic scenario. Basically what i have to achieve is to add children over children with different colors and different stroke size as the finger moves over canvas.

I am attaching my current logic so please tell me where I am lagging.

Thanks in Advance.

Code:

```
    void myCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);
        oldPoint = currentPoint;
    } 

    void myCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);
            Line line = new Line() { X1 = currentPoint.X, Y1 = currentPoint.Y, X2 = oldPoint.X, Y2 = oldPoint.Y };
            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(myColor);
            line.StrokeThickness = 10;
            line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            this.myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
            oldPoint = currentPoint;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i worked on something very alike not too long ago, when i had problems i found this.

[Derik Whittaker](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/03/25/how-to-capture-user-signatures-on-wp7.aspx)

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: First of all thanks Derik for ur solution. I tested it on my device and the performace of capturing points and drawing has been increased tremendously. I am now able to draw over points. But still the problem which is there is when I am moving my finger fastly over canvas small straight lines are still there. Other problem which has now come is on drawing letters like V, W, M etc (having edges) pointed edges are being drawn like if we make a zigzag line extra pointed edges are drawn...can this be handled by some property of line.

Comment: Not that i know of, but definitely would continue research on this. The MSDN or WP7 Dev would be a good place to start. Takes longer to get an answer but they will be very helpful.

Comment: also go to MSDN.com and look for the Class Reference on the brush and see what it all has accessible.

Comment: Sorry, Keeano I referred u as Derik as I was more focussed on writing the content. Thanks alot for all ur help!!

Comment: No problem, Derik is truly a good programmer...i follow many of his blogs from game design to WP7 and silverlight.